# How to take multiple inputs from user using for loop?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(n - 1):
        nums = int(input('Enter numbers: '))
```

INPUT:

```
Enter numbers: 1
Enter numbers: 2
Enter numbers: 3
Enter numbers: 4
```

This is the output I am getting but I want the output to be in a single line, numbers that I am entering should be in a single line like 1 2 3 4. No commas no apostrophe

Please tell any solution

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask if you want the output to have no commas and no apostrophe after inputting the above 4 numbers?

Comment: I want to take multiple inputs like eg 5 in a single attempt and add those inputs

Comment: You can use `join` to get your output

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for a single input and then split it into words with the `str.split()` method

```
# Get the input
nums = input('Enter numbers :')

# Split and map to `int`
nums = nums.split()
nums = list(map(int, nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append it first into a list

```
def myfunction(n):
    return [input('Enter numbers: ' for _ in range(n - 1)]

numbers = myfunction(5)

Enter numbers: 1
Enter numbers: 2
Enter numbers: 3
Enter numbers: 4
```

And then, you can use `" ".join(numbers)`

```
result = " ".join(numbers)
print(result)

1 2 3 4
```

If you do not even want to have the space:

```
result2 = "".join(numbers)
print(result2)

1234
```